# Is there a word mirroring common usage of "proportional" (which I characterize as "monotonically increasing as a function of")?

Tags: single-word-requests

In mathematics, a and b are proportional if their ratio, a/b is constant (DEFINITION 1).

In common language, proportional is often used to mean something more like "when a goes up, b also goes up (and vice versa)" (DEFINITION 2).

I'm looking for a word *other than "proportional"* which matches DEFINITION 2.

Comment: Have you already rejected the options provided by a thesaurus? http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/proportional?s=t

Comment: @filistinist - I had not, thanks.  None of them seem quite right, I'm thinking I might try out "commensurably", though.

Comment: Maths language isn't so complex without good reason.

Comment: Can you add a sentence showing how you want to use the word? That will help us have a better handle on the register you want, what part(s) of speech would work for you, etc. (and it's technically [required for single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)).

Answer (score 4):

The word that springs to mind for me is ***[correlated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/correlated)***:

> to bear reciprocal or mutual relations :  correspond · If two things correlate, a change in one thing results in a similar or opposite change in the other thing.
>   <sub>from *[m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/correlated)*</sub>

A correlation can be either *positive* (as A goes up, B also goes up) or *negative* (as A goes up, B goes down).  In the absence of a qualifier, a positive correlation is generally assumed, so you should definitely specify when a correlation is negative. (You may want to specify positive correlations as well, just to be complete.)

Comment: I don't believe that "correlation" and "proportionality" are synonyms. The former suggests there is a mutual relationship. But two things can be proportional without there being any relationship between them. There is, for example, an inverse relationship between the number of letters in the names of the month, and northern hemisphere air temperatures. *Inverse proportionality* exists but the two things are not *correlated*.

Comment: @WS2 It appears to me that your argument is based on the common logical fallacy of believing that *correlation = causation*.   (Also, "correlate" was listed as a possibility in filistinist's thesaurus link on the question.)

Comment: 'I don't believe that "correlation" and "proportionality" are synonyms.' Correct. The OP is explicitly asking for something that is not a synonym. "Correlation", or, for many scientific contexts, "Positive Correlation", seems like a perfect answer to me.

Comment: [ODO](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/correlate) (and other dictionaries) must have fallen foul of this common logical fallacy then: << correlate
... 1. verb
If one thing correlates with another, there is a close similarity or connection between them, often because one thing causes the other.  >> The definition of 'correlation' many mathematicians use is not the only valid one, and is probably not the principal one globally. // I'm not saying that 'correlation' isn't usable hereabouts, but there is now another different-senses problem here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth on the contrary, your quote specifically hedges: "**often** because one thing causes the other".  :-)

Comment: I think you'd better replace the non-standard equal sign if you want to be clear. Certainly, the two words aren't equivalent (which would perhaps be shown by the equivalence sign), but they are synonyms. The problem here is the range of senses each may have, and the question of range of synonymity. [CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/correlation) gives a very broad definition of correlation: <<  a connection or relationship between two or more facts, numbers, etc.:
_There's a correlation between smoking and cancer._ >> This doesn't necessitate a monotonically ...

Comment: increasing functional relationship. // This question exposes the gap between precisionist and everyday language where they try to address the same issues – and the problems when terms are ill-defined, as with 'proportional' and 'correlation', having different senses in different registers.

Comment: I think to fully match the OP's desired definition ("when a goes up, b also goes up") you should probably specify "positively correlated", at least as a note. Although "in common usage" I suspect it's at least as fuzzy a concept as "proportional".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't know what "non-standard equal sign" you are referring to....

Comment: @1006a good idea, duly implemented.  Thanks!

Comment: Used between two words. 'Non-standard / ill-defined use of the equals sign' if you insist. << small = little >> is unclear as the equals sign is only well-defined in maths usage. Equality is well-defined; synonymity is far harder to analyse and characterise.